# javascript onmouse out not working

Tags: javascript, css, onmouseover, background-position, onmouseout

Basically I transformed a rollover from my css to javascript. I also chose one of the pictures to be selected once the page is loaded. But am having trouble with the onMouseOut event. Everything works perfect except that picture. When I hover over other pictures that picture remains selected. I tried multiple ways but don't know how to fix it.. any ideas?

```
<script type="text/javascript">

window.onload=function(){
clicked3();
}

function clicked3(){
document.getElementById("clicked3").style.backgroundPosition = "-198px top";
}

function handleOver3() { 
 if (document.getElementById("clicked3")) document.style.backgroundPosition="-198px top";
 }


function handleOut3() {
 if (document.getElementById("clicked3")) document.style.backgroundPosition="0px top";
}

</script>
```

Comment: Your backgroundPosition in handleOver is the same as when it was loaded

Comment: well yeah, I also want that picture to change once I hover over it. Its firstly selected but when I hover other pictures I want it to be deselected. Once I hover over it again I want it to be selected again

Comment: Can you provide the html associated with the question?

Comment: use too class: class 1 for first picture, class 2 for the second picture. When hover, check which class it is, then change to the other class. If you do like this, every time you hover on the image, it's still the same

Comment: It was working perfectly fine when i put the onmouseover and onmouseout events within my html but i want it fully javascript instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't showed an registration of handlers for *onmouseover* and *onmouseout* events? Next code example may help you.

HTML:

```
<div id='clicked1' style='width:140px;height:183px;background:URL(http://t3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQbcDkaRcrbsYFUcE6Q7n56_LJr-r4mDqYTOTtPKG9J0MzZcV6V)' />
<div id='clicked2' style='width:140px;height:183px;background:URL(http://t3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQbcDkaRcrbsYFUcE6Q7n56_LJr-r4mDqYTOTtPKG9J0MzZcV6V)' />
<div id='clicked3' style='width:140px;height:183px;background:URL(http://t3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQbcDkaRcrbsYFUcE6Q7n56_LJr-r4mDqYTOTtPKG9J0MzZcV6V)' />
```

SCRIPT:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

window.onload=function() {
    var domClicked1=document.getElementById("clicked1");
    var domClicked2=document.getElementById("clicked2");
    var domClicked3=document.getElementById("clicked3");
    clicked.call(domClicked1);
    clicked.call(domClicked2);
    clicked.call(domClicked3);
    domClicked1.onmouseover=
    domClicked2.onmouseover=
    domClicked3.onmouseover=handleOver; // but you must switch to use addEventListener (or attachEvent for IE8 and less)
    domClicked1.onmouseout=
    domClicked2.onmouseout=
    domClicked3.onmouseout=handleOut;
}

function clicked(){
    this.style.backgroundPosition = "-140px top";
}

function handleOver() {
    this.style.backgroundPosition = "0px top";
}

function handleOut() {
    this.style.backgroundPosition = "-140px top";
}

</script>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/J2SrF/

Comment: You must add _onmouseover_ and _onmouseout_ for all pictures separately. See updated post.

Comment: It somehow works but thats like calling all the functions onload.. it loads all the pictures from the beginning and it messes some of them. Am still working on it..

Comment: I haven't found any solutions yet.. Its like when am hovering over the clicked1 picture now, the clicked1 pic stays unselected and clicked3 pic still selected....any ideas?

Comment: it works if i don't call the other functions from the beginning

Comment: I dont understand what is _it works if i don't call the other functions from the beginning_ But (as I wrote in the post) you must use addEventListener: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.addEventListener or attachEvent: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536343%28v=vs.85%29.aspx for best results. For example: if(window.addEventListener) {domClicked1.addEventListener('mouseover',handleOver,false);domClicked2.addEventListener('mouseover',handleOver,false);/*for all elements*/}else if(window.attachEvent){domClicked1.attachEvent('onmouseover',handleOver);/*for all elements*/}

Comment: what i meant is that I shouldn't add   clicked.call(domClicked1); to all pictures because the only picture I want to be active in the beginning is picture3

Answer (score 0):

it works like this!!

```
window.onload=function() {


    var domClicked1=document.getElementById("clicked1");
    var domClicked2=document.getElementById("clicked2");
    var domClicked3=document.getElementById("clicked3");
    var domClicked4=document.getElementById("clicked4");



    clicked3.call(domClicked3);

    domClicked1.onmouseover=handleOver1;
    domClicked1.onmouseout=handleOut1;

    domClicked2.onmouseover=handleOver2;
    domClicked2.onmouseout=handleOut2;

    domClicked3.onmouseover=handleOver3; 
    domClicked3.onmouseout=handleOut3;

    domClicked4.onmouseover=handleOver4;
    domClicked4.onmouseout=handleOut4;

}


function handleOver1(){
document.getElementById("clicked3").style.backgroundPosition="0px top";
}

function handleOut1(){
document.getElementById("clicked3").style.backgroundPosition="0px top";
}

function handleOver2(){
document.getElementById("clicked3").style.backgroundPosition="0px top";
}

function handleOut2(){
document.getElementById("clicked3").style.backgroundPosition="0px top";
}




function clicked3(){
    this.style.backgroundPosition = "-198px top";
}

function handleOver3() {
    this.style.backgroundPosition = "-198px top";
}

function handleOut3() {
    this.style.backgroundPosition = "0px top";
}

function handleOver4(){
document.getElementById("clicked3").style.backgroundPosition="0px top";
}

function handleOut4(){
document.getElementById("clicked3").style.backgroundPosition="0px top";
}
```